# SearchView does not work

Tags: java, android, android-studio, searchview, android-search

I'm trying to do a SearchView with a item from Menu Settings but when I run the project in my android, the app stops. I tried to use MenuItemCompat because I saw in some codes that It is used to this case but with the new version of Android Studio It doesn't exist. I'm using API 22:

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener{

TextView texto;
private SearchView searchview;
private MenuItem searchmenuitem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    searchmenuitem = menu.findItem(R.id.buscar);
    searchview = (SearchView) searchmenuitem.getActionView();
    searchview.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    searchmenuitem.setOnActionExpandListener(this);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    texto.setText(newText);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "EXPAND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "COLLAPSE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
}
}
```

menu_main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" android:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/buscar"
    android:title="buscar"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
 </menu>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/texto"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="131dp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your log that shows the error why your application stopped

Comment: When start the app say "unfortunately Busqueda has stopped"